# C# HttpListener создать сервер с именем

Tags: c#, http

создаю сервер

```
lstnr = new Server();
lstnr.url = "http://" + ipbox.Text;
```

ip иногда меняется. приходится подгонять его на клиенте. можно ли задать серверу текстовый адрес типа mysite.ru как в денвере?

Comment: Да, `localhost`.

Comment: @LLENN прочитайте вопрос

Comment: У меня мало опыта в C#, но скорее всего кроме как использовать IIS - никак.  
P.S.: используйте конфигурационный файл, вместо `ipbox`.